# PHP: Need advice on form validation on a server with PHP v5.1.3

Tags: php, jquery, html, validation

I'm trying to learn how to do server-side validation on a web form using PHP. I already have the client-side validation working through jQuery. During my studies I read something about native validation filters added to PHP v5.2 that does much of the grunt work for form validation. Unfortunately, I just learned that my office server is running PHP v5.1.3. Ouch! To make a long story short, we can not upgrade the PHP version. End of discussion.

As a newbie to all of this, **are there other readily available functions out there that would help me validate form input data for older versions of PHP that do just as good of a job?** I read something about HTML_QuickForm2, but I already have my form built in HTML5 (using a polyfill to help older browsers like IE8 validate HTML5 forms).

Again, new to all this and looking to be nudged into the right direction so I can get this form validated as quickly as possible.

Comment: It shouldn't be the end of the discussion, 5.1.3 was released in **2006**

Comment: Update your server, period. There is no reason you couldn't or shouldn't.

Comment: I can't upgrade the server because I am not authorized to make those decisions. Pathetic, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

As a starter, I would suggest you look into HTML5 -- by default, you have some (very) basic validation for certain field types (`email`, `tel`, `date`...).

Next, I would look into PHP's `preg_match`; this will help you match inputs to certain strings. First step would be to start reading a few articles on PHP validation. [Here's an introductory article on the subject.](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Validating-User-Input.html) Another good source, which requires some time and effort, would be to go straight to the source at [php.net](http://php.net).

Answer (score 0):

The native validation filters (assuming email primarily) could be replaced with a simple regular expression. As for others, string length checks, is_numeric checks and regex for more complex stuff will do the trick.

But really: upgrade that server (or install a secondary one). PHP 5.1 is just ancient.